# How do I set ExceptionHandled on an ActionExecutedContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'm using an ActionFilter (that I did not write) on an action method. The action method itself calls a SaveOrUpdate() method on a repository. If that SaveOrUpdate() method fails with an exception I would like to set the ExceptionHandled property of ActionExecutedContext from within the action method so the OnActionExecuted method will not attempt to commit the transaction.

How can I do that? Is this the right way to approach this or should I be doing this differently?

Here's the code in OnActionExecuted of the filter:

```
public  void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var thereWereNoExceptions = filterContext.Exception == null || filterContext.ExceptionHandled;
        if (filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && thereWereNoExceptions)
        {
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this. Just throw an exception:

```
[MyFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    throw new Exception("foo");
}
```

and the `else` statement of your `OnActionExecuted` filter will be hit and rollback the transaction.

Comment: Hmmm, an exception being thrown from the action method is how I discovered the problem in the first place. In the end I decided to catch the exception and add a ModelState error. The else statement  then kicks in because it tests if the ModelState.IsValid.

Comment: @Simon, that's strange. I am not able to reproduce the behavior. I wrote a custom action filter attribute deriving from `ActionFilterAttribute` and overrode the `OnActionExecuted` by placing the exact same test as in your case. Then I decorated my controller action with this custom attribute and when an exception was thrown in the controller action the `else` statement is executed. How's your scenario different than mine? Does your action attribute derive from `ActionFilterAttribute` or are you simply implementing the `IActionFilter` interface?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to handle custom errors.

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```